# Can't left align UI Bootstrap Dropdown Submenus

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having issues trying to left align my submenus within a `UI Bootstrap` `uib-dropdown` control.  Because my dropdown falls too close to the right hand side of the page, I need the submenu to push out from the left hand side, however, by default it appears underneath the parent:
[image]

If I add `pull-left` to my submenu, it appears to the left, but still underneath:
[image]

When I try and access the submenu, it disappears.  I need it to appear to the left hand side (directly next to the parent menu item).

My code looks like so:

```
<div uib-dropdown>
    <a id="options" href class="panel-tools-configure" uib-dropdown-toggle uib-tooltip="Options"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" uib-dropdown-menu>
            <li role="menuitem"><a href><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span> Gallery View</a></li>
            <li role="menuitem"><a href><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></span> List View</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown-header">Sorting</li>
            <li class="dropdown-submenu pull-left">
                <a href="#">Sort By: {{ sortBy }}</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" uib-dropdown-menu>
                    <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Site ID</a></li>
                    <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Site Name</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

My CSS code:

```
.dropdown-submenu {
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover>.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-submenu>a:after {
    display: block;
    content: " ";
    float: right;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;
    border-left-color: #ccc;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-right: -10px;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover>a:after {
    border-left-color: #fff;
}

.dropdown-submenu.pull-left {
    float: none;
}

.dropdown-submenu.pull-left>.dropdown-menu {
    left: -100%;
    margin-left: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
    border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
}
```

Comment: Can you push your code on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: need to see a fiddle or more of your code, dropdown-submenu is not part of bootstrap

Comment: I'm working on a JSFiddle but I've never used this before, so it's taking me a while sorry.  The `dropdown-submenu` was taken from [here](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/multi-level-dropdown-menu-bs3)

Comment: Updated my post with my CSS code as I'm having too much trouble setting up jsfiddle